# Need help identifying a vintage road bike, possible Benotto 3000

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

I have this bike that I bought at a local store, I'm from Costa Rica> The manager sold it to me as a Benotto, but I can not find anything that tells me that it is apart from the stickers. The headtube lugs have a form that I have not been able to find in any other type of vintage bicycle. Is it simply a generic frame of the 80s?

On the bottom bracket shell it says only JSP 251

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I find this for "Benotto": https://www.steel-vintage.com/benotto

Comment: Otherwise, "generic frame from the 80s" is about right, though it could be the 90s.  The plastic cable guide, non-cottered cranks, and downtube shifters suggest that it's newer than the 70s.

Comment: (I suspect that if you dig into the Benotto brand you may find that they were manufactured in South America during the years of interest.)

Comment: This may help: https://machiine.com/2015/benotto-classic/

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately I did not see a similar, the more I see my bike the more it seems to me that it is only a generic one, I hope someone identifies it, but it is interesting that thing you mention of the 90s, I did not know that detail, I will look for similar 90s bikes ...

Comment: It does look very much similar to the Modelo 5000 models, though they spanned several years.  I doubt that you can nail it down to a specific year.  If your decals are a good match to the ones in that link then it's doubtful that you have a forgery.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the brands stamped on the brake arms, et al.

Comment: And note that the decal down the seat post may indicate where the bike was manufactured.

Comment: Could be this one?? 

https://www.usedvictoria.com/ReportSelectUsedAdPhoto2?used_ad_id=32404087&position=4&hb=1

Comment: Or maybe this one?? 

https://www.pedalroom.com/bike/1984-schwinn-world-olds-35259

Comment: Quite close but not exact match. Head tube lugs are almost exact match but the dropouts are different and the Schwinns have cable guides brazed into frame over the bottom bracket.

Comment: You are right they are different!, back to searching..., I thought I had it, at least at this point I think I can be sure that it is a Schwinn and not a Benotto after all. I saw this video on YouTube and I thought it was, but no! they are different again hahaha

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWiblTEfz08&list=LLZ-janCt5OsYZOBWX9D0Uxg&index=2&t=0s

Comment: Why do you feel it's not a Benotto?

Comment: I cannot find a single Benotto with those lugs, did I miss something?? I will check your links again, thanks

Comment: OMG Found it! Local Bike Paint Shop here in Costa Rica had a Guru that help me out when I showed it to him asking for a Benotto paint job

Comment: Its a JAISA 251, steel frame! not Aluminum and it suposed to be a originally fitted with aero components (lol) at the time, wich happens to be a defunct Bike Brand that existed in 70s and 80s, a little search in facebook found me some  similar ones. Will be posting updates of the paint job. Thanks everyone for your help :-D

Comment: Here is a link to a similar one for sale https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1248665155150151&set=a.534395929910414&type=3&theater